# Import SCSS folder from global SCSS

Tags: css, angular, sass

I'm using Angular (Jhipster) on my application and I want to import several .scss files on my glocal.scss file. So I created an "util" folder (same level as global.scss file) and added these .scss partials inside it. On top of my global.scss file, I treid to do:

```
@import "util";

@import "util/*";

@import "util/;
```

And other alternatives, but I'm receiving this error:

> Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):
>
> undefined
>          ^
>         Can't find stylesheet to import.

When I import one file at a time, it works.

How can I import a folder with .scss files inside my global .scss file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doesn't look like you can import a directory/folder based on [this](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#import).

What you can do is in your utils folder create an index sass file that imports all the partials then importing utils should work based on [this](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#index_files).